# iOS app-level communication over USB

Tags: ios, usb, tunneling

Is it possible to to communicate between MAC/Windows programs and an application on iOS through USB?

Requirements:

- No jailbreak required
- App store approval

I looked into USBMuxConnectByPort and it requires SSH/Jailbreak.

Is there any other option?

Comment: For OSX & iOS check out the http://rsms.me/peertalk/. For Win i have no idea...

Comment: any progress on this? I have been using Wi-Fi for desktop<->iOS communication, but I need a performance boost in the transfer rate, so USB should be great.

Comment: AFAIK 'USBMuxConnectByPort' does not require jailbreak

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.
'USBMuxConnectByPort' is the function from the private framework MobileDevice.framework
See usage example here: https://github.com/smirn0v/imux
imux – application I wrote that ties local tcp port on your mac with tcp port on your ipad/iphone. So connection to 127.0.0.1:someport will actually connect you to your iPhone/iPad via usb.

Comment: do you know if there is a chance to connect to a normal computer via usb? For lets say message based communication with a 1s interval? For example json or xml messages?